# nginx map default value from a file?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have a nginx map defined like below

```
map $foo $bar {
    default "xyz"
}
```

My question is can the default value come from a file content? Something like below

```
map $foo $bar {
    default file /tmp/myfile
}
```

where the contents of /tmp/myfile is "xyz"

Answer (score 1):

I would use `include /tmp/myfile;` where `myfile` contains:

```
    default xyz;
```